# how to list all local users

Tags: linux, users, nis

I have a NIS client machine which has many users. Some of them were local (created on that machine), some of them were NIS users (created on NIS server, ever logged in and created home directories). How can I just list all local users?

Comment: Local users will be in `/etc/passwd`

Comment: Not sure how portable this is, so just a comment: `getent passwd | cut -d : -f 1`